# How to relative urls in Django URLField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How i can get relative urls in my field after serialize? now i get abolute.
My model:

```
class Article(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField()
    text = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField()
```

And serializer:

```
class ArticleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    link = URLField()
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, without the `http://...` prefix, the url will not be a valid url. If you want to link somewhere inside your app, you can take the output of something like django's reverse and store it in a CharField (or just do some string manipulation by declaring a method, prior to inserting to the database or prior to serialization-deserialization).